# Listing top products based on sales quantity

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a development of an earlier problem I had posted and accepted an answer for.

I'm looking to sort a list of products based on their total sales, but I wish to include the product AND their total sales in the result table (see image).

I know now (based on a previous answer given to me) how to get the top items, but I'm stuck how to get the sales values too.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A3:B12,
     _Product, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Product),
     TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(_Uniq,MMULT(N(_Uniq=TOROW(_Product)),TAKE(_Data,,-1))),2,-1),5))
```

---

Or, Using `BYROW()`

```
=LET(
     _Data, A3:B12,
     _Product, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Product),
     _TotalSales, BYROW(_Uniq, LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=_Product)*TAKE(_Data,,-1)))),
     TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(_Uniq, _TotalSales),2,-1),5))
```

---

Or Using `GROUPBY()` if applicable:

```
=TAKE(GROUPBY(A3:A12,B3:B12,SUM,,0,-2),5)
```

---

Or using `SUMIF()` or `SUMIFS()`

```
=LET(α, A3:A12, TAKE(UNIQUE(SORT(HSTACK(α,SUMIF(α,α,B3:B12)),2,-1)),5))
```

---